# With known parameters in equation, how to calculate a third unknown one

Tags: r, math

The following equation `f(t)= b*pow(1-exp(-k*t), b-1) – (b-1)*pow(1-exp(-k*t), b)` is used to describe a curve.

When `f(t)=0.5` with known `b` and `k`, how to calculate it in R?

```
b*pow(1-exp(-k*t),b-1) –(b-1)*pow(1-exp(-k*t),b) = 0.5
```

e.g. when `b=5`, `k=0.5`, `t=?`

Comment: How would you solve for `t` without R?

Comment: I am current using Excel solver, but I can only do it one by one. When I have 100 data, It take ages to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use uniroot, but first plot the function to check for roots, if any. I extract 0.5 from the function, since that is what you want to solve for. Plotting shows that there are two roots, so you have to play with th interval in the uniroot function. I'll leave that to you, let me know if you struggle with it.

```
f <- function(x)
{
  b=5
  k=0.5
  return( b* (1- exp(-k*x))^(b-1) - (b-1) * (1-exp(-k*x))^b  -0.5 )
}

uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 1e+08))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I do it with a batch instead of assign a number to b and k receptively.